# How to display the text field component together with graph on dashboard?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I need you help.
The problem is as follows:

1. I created the report.

[image: Report]

2. I want to add this report on dashboard. But there is a problem. When I add this report on dashboard, the View button isn't displayed. View - text field.

[image: Dashboard]

Why does this occur? and how to make so that "View" also is displayed?

**Source code:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-01-26T23:23:55 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Summary_Clicks Report_2" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="572" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="9ac8b394-36b0-409a-8a94-b8147d9c2d20">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.border.collapse" value="separate"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.frames.as.nested.tables" value="false"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.actual.size" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.group.indent" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.min.group.label.width" value="100"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.detail.band.height" value="25"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.header.band.height" value="25"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.crosstab.row.header.width" value="125"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.crosstab.cell.width" value="100"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.crosstab.cell.height" value="20"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc" value="1"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.preferredDataStrategy" value="domainDataStrategy"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tagged" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.language" value="EN-US"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..."/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="false"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://stats.trackif.com/jasperserver-pro/services/repository/"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="superuser"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/organizations/organization_1/reports/Summary_Clicks_Report_2"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/organizations/organization_1/reports/Summary_Clicks_Report_2_files/mainReportJrxml"/>
    <import value="com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.jr.AdhocReportUtils"/>
    <import value="com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.service.AdhocEngineServiceImpl"/>
    <style name="ReportDefault" isDefault="true" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11">
        <box>
            <pen lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableBaseFrameStyle" mode="Transparent">
        <box padding="0">
            <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
        <box padding="1">
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableColumnHeaderFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableColumnFooterFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableColumnHeaderTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#D5DEE8" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true">
        <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableGroupHeaderFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#E3E9EF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableGroupHeaderTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#E3E9EF" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true">
        <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableGroupFooterFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#E7ECF2">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableGroupFooterTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#E7ECF2" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true">
        <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableSummaryFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
        <box>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableSummaryTextNoBorderStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" fontName="DejaVu Sans" isBold="true">
        <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5"/>
    </style>
    <style name="TableSummaryTextStyle" style="TableSummaryTextNoBorderStyle">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableTitleFrameStyle" style="TableFrameStyle">
        <box topPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
            <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableTitleTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#333333" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Center" hImageAlign="Center" fontSize="18" isBold="false">
        <box bottomPadding="8">
            <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableDetailFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
        <box>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableDetailTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="false">
        <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="ChartReportTitle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#333333" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Center" hImageAlign="Center" fontSize="18" isBold="false">
        <box>
            <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="ChartTitle" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="ChartSubtitle" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="9" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="ChartLegend" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="9" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor0" backcolor="#87C4FE"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor1" backcolor="#E96270"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor2" backcolor="#D1D1D1"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor3" backcolor="#FFEE99"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor4" backcolor="#6164FF"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor5" backcolor="#B0E992"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor6" backcolor="#AE9CEA"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor7" backcolor="#F5B05E"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor8" backcolor="#589EE1"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor9" backcolor="#AE4E59"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor10" backcolor="#747474"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor11" backcolor="#E2DC77"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor12" backcolor="#4749A5"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor13" backcolor="#81B963"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor14" backcolor="#7764B4"/>
    <style name="ChartSeriesColor15" backcolor="#F27B4C"/>
    <style name="ChartCategoryAxisLabelFormat" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="ChartCategoryAxisTickFormat" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="9" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="ChartValueAxisLabelFormat" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="ChartValueAxisTickFormat" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="9" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="ChartContext" backcolor="#D1CA67"/>
    <style name="CrosstabElementStyle" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#000033" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Center" hImageAlign="Center" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11">
        <box bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
            <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="CrosstabBaseCellStyle" mode="Transparent">
        <box padding="0">
            <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Top" vImageAlign="Top" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true">
        <box topPadding="3" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="3" rightPadding="5">
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="CrosstabTitleTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" forecolor="#333333" fontSize="18" isBold="false">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="CrosstabHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#D5DEE8"/>
    <style name="CrosstabHeaderLabelStyle" style="CrosstabHeaderTextStyle" mode="Transparent">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="CrosstabMeasureHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#D3C8EB"/>
    <style name="CrosstabMeasureHeaderLabelStyle" style="CrosstabMeasureHeaderTextStyle" mode="Transparent">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="CrosstabColumnMeasureHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabMeasureHeaderTextStyle"/>
    <style name="CrosstabRowMeasureHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabMeasureHeaderTextStyle" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="CrosstabDimensionHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#E7ECF2" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="CrosstabDetailTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Right" hImageAlign="Right" isBold="false">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{CROSSTAB_TOTAL_DISCRIMINATOR}]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#F0F4F8" hTextAlign="Right" hImageAlign="Right" isBold="true">
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
                </box>
            </style>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="CrosstabDummyHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#D4D4D4"/>
    <parameter name="REPORT_TITLE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.cache.included" value="true"/>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="_JRS_ADHOC_CHART_STATE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.cache.included" value="true"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="_JRS_ADHOC_QUERY_DATA" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.cache.included" value="true"/>
    </parameter>
    <field name="summary_date" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="public_dashboard_by_day_materialized.clicks_count1" class="java.lang.Long">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[public_dashboard_by_day_materialized.clicks_count1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="public_dashboard_by_day_materialized.summary_date1" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[public_dashboard_by_day_materialized.summary_date1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Sum_clicks_count" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <title>
        <band height="621" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="chart" positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="-11" y="70" width="572" height="265" uuid="32d0daf7-6eea-46f4-bfcf-e0f9bdb5ce46"/>
                <jrhc:chart xmlns:jrhc="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts http://jaspersoft.com/schema/highcharts.xsd" type="Area" preferredHeight="353" evaluationTime="Page">
                    <jrhc:chartSetting name="_jrs_adhoc">
                        <jrhc:chartProperty name="_JRS_ADHOC_CHART_STATE">
                            <jrhc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[$P{_JRS_ADHOC_CHART_STATE}]]></jrhc:propertyExpression>
                        </jrhc:chartProperty>
                        <jrhc:chartProperty name="_JRS_ADHOC_QUERY_DATA">
                            <jrhc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[$P{_JRS_ADHOC_QUERY_DATA}]]></jrhc:propertyExpression>
                        </jrhc:chartProperty>
                    </jrhc:chartSetting>
                </jrhc:chart>
            </componentElement>
            <textField hyperlinkType="Reference" hyperlinkTarget="Blank">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="240" y="30" width="119" height="30" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#7FFF00" uuid="010a3c43-3629-455a-a522-2dad2b5e33cd">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class" value="btn"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.id" value="idBtn"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["View"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["myButton"]]></anchorNameExpression>
                <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://google.ru"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
                <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Click to view"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Is the view button inside your report?, show the jrxml...

Comment: It is very strange...

Comment: Remove  positionType="Float" from the reportElement containing the chart

Comment: I can't reproduce it, try to set x=0 instead of -11 and then look at the generated html to see if the button is there somewhere.... a problem with html rendering??, if its there use for example developer tools on chrome to understand where it is...

Comment: I would also remove this on the button, isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true"  seems to have no sense

Comment: It does not seem related but if you have no datasource, just the graph on the jasperReport tag you should have whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" ,

Comment: I created the button in the standard report. As example. There the same problem is observed.

Comment: I see you have html.id and html.class, you got some strange javascript or css that removes the button? More then this I can't help you since I can't reproduce the error.... Did you find it in the html??

Comment: No, nothing like that

Answer (score 0):

I created the button in the standard report. As example. There the same problem is observed. 
Maybe you will be able to reproduce this code?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-01-27T00:02:06 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="06. Sales Mix by Gender Report" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="572" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="7bd0a5cf-8cc1-4e6d-8ed7-178a04c17a8c">
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span" value="false"/>
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.border.collapse" value="separate"/>
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.frames.as.nested.tables" value="false"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.actual.size" value="true"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.group.indent" value="0"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.min.group.label.width" value="100"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.detail.band.height" value="25"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.header.band.height" value="25"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.crosstab.row.header.width" value="125"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.crosstab.cell.width" value="100"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.adhoc.crosstab.cell.height" value="20"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc" value="1"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.preferredDataStrategy" value="sqlQueryDataStrategy"/>
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tagged" value="true"/>
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.language" value="EN-US"/>
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..."/>
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="false"/>
 <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://stats.trackif.com/jasperserver-pro/services/repository/"/>
 <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="superuser"/>
 <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/public/Samples/Reports/Report_for_example"/>
 <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/public/Samples/Reports/Report_for_example_files/mainReportJrxml"/>
 <import value="com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.jr.AdhocReportUtils"/>
 <import value="com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.service.AdhocEngineServiceImpl"/>
 <style name="ReportDefault" isDefault="true" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11">
  <box>
   <pen lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableBaseFrameStyle" mode="Transparent">
  <box padding="0">
   <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
  <box padding="1">
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableColumnHeaderFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
  <box>
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableColumnFooterFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
  <box>
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableColumnHeaderTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#D5DEE8" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true">
  <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
   <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableGroupHeaderFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#E3E9EF">
  <box>
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableGroupHeaderTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#E3E9EF" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true">
  <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableGroupFooterFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#E7ECF2">
  <box>
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableGroupFooterTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#E7ECF2" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true">
  <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableSummaryFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
  <box>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableSummaryTextNoBorderStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" fontName="DejaVu Sans" isBold="true">
  <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5"/>
 </style>
 <style name="TableSummaryTextStyle" style="TableSummaryTextNoBorderStyle">
  <box>
   <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableTitleFrameStyle" style="TableFrameStyle">
  <box topPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
   <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableTitleTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#333333" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Center" hImageAlign="Center" fontSize="18" isBold="false">
  <box bottomPadding="8">
   <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
   <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableDetailFrameStyle" style="TableBaseFrameStyle">
  <box>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="TableDetailTextStyle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="false">
  <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
   <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="ChartReportTitle" style="ReportDefault" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#333333" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Center" hImageAlign="Center" fontSize="18" isBold="false">
  <box>
   <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
   <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="ChartTitle" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
 <style name="ChartSubtitle" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="9" isBold="false"/>
 <style name="ChartLegend" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="9" isBold="false"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor0" backcolor="#87C4FE"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor1" backcolor="#E96270"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor2" backcolor="#D1D1D1"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor3" backcolor="#FFEE99"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor4" backcolor="#6164FF"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor5" backcolor="#B0E992"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor6" backcolor="#AE9CEA"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor7" backcolor="#F5B05E"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor8" backcolor="#589EE1"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor9" backcolor="#AE4E59"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor10" backcolor="#747474"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor11" backcolor="#E2DC77"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor12" backcolor="#4749A5"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor13" backcolor="#81B963"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor14" backcolor="#7764B4"/>
 <style name="ChartSeriesColor15" backcolor="#F27B4C"/>
 <style name="ChartCategoryAxisLabelFormat" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true"/>
 <style name="ChartCategoryAxisTickFormat" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="9" isBold="false"/>
 <style name="ChartValueAxisLabelFormat" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true"/>
 <style name="ChartValueAxisTickFormat" forecolor="#000000" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="9" isBold="false"/>
 <style name="ChartContext" backcolor="#D1CA67"/>
 <style name="CrosstabElementStyle" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#000033" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Center" hImageAlign="Center" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11">
  <box bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
   <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#AAAAAA"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="CrosstabBaseCellStyle" mode="Transparent">
  <box padding="0">
   <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Left" hImageAlign="Left" vTextAlign="Top" vImageAlign="Top" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11" isBold="true">
  <box topPadding="3" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="3" rightPadding="5">
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#B1B6BB"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="CrosstabTitleTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" forecolor="#333333" fontSize="18" isBold="false">
  <box>
   <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="CrosstabHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#D5DEE8"/>
 <style name="CrosstabHeaderLabelStyle" style="CrosstabHeaderTextStyle" mode="Transparent">
  <box>
   <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="CrosstabMeasureHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#D3C8EB"/>
 <style name="CrosstabMeasureHeaderLabelStyle" style="CrosstabMeasureHeaderTextStyle" mode="Transparent">
  <box>
   <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
  </box>
 </style>
 <style name="CrosstabColumnMeasureHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabMeasureHeaderTextStyle"/>
 <style name="CrosstabRowMeasureHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabMeasureHeaderTextStyle" isBold="false"/>
 <style name="CrosstabDimensionHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#E7ECF2" isBold="false"/>
 <style name="CrosstabDetailTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#FFFFFF" hTextAlign="Right" hImageAlign="Right" isBold="false">
  <box>
   <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
   <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
  </box>
  <conditionalStyle>
   <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{CROSSTAB_TOTAL_DISCRIMINATOR}]]></conditionExpression>
   <style backcolor="#F0F4F8" hTextAlign="Right" hImageAlign="Right" isBold="true">
    <box>
     <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#E3E9EF"/>
    </box>
   </style>
  </conditionalStyle>
 </style>
 <style name="CrosstabDummyHeaderTextStyle" style="CrosstabBaseTextStyle" backcolor="#D4D4D4"/>
 <parameter name="REPORT_TITLE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.cache.included" value="true"/>
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="_JRS_ADHOC_CHART_STATE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.cache.included" value="true"/>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="_JRS_ADHOC_QUERY_DATA" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.cache.included" value="true"/>
 </parameter>
 <field name="c_gender" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[c_gender]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>
 <field name="store_sales" class="java.lang.Double">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[store_sales]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>
 <field name="product_family" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product_family]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>
 <field name="c_country" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[c_country]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>
 <field name="Sum_store_sales" class="java.lang.Double"/>
 <field name="quarter" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[quarter]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>
 <title>
  <band height="335" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement key="staticText" style="ChartReportTitle" x="0" y="0" width="572" height="0" uuid="487722f7-0dd2-4fb0-86f6-e937ad83ff06">
     <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_TITLE} != null && $P{REPORT_TITLE}.length() > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_TITLE}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <componentElement>
    <reportElement key="chart" positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="5" y="5" width="572" height="330" uuid="8bc741d5-26ae-4474-a53f-d5ab6beb9a31"/>
    <jrhc:chart xmlns:jrhc="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts http://jaspersoft.com/schema/highcharts.xsd" type="StackedPercentBar" preferredHeight="353">
     <jrhc:chartSetting name="_jrs_adhoc">
      <jrhc:chartProperty name="_JRS_ADHOC_CHART_STATE">
       <jrhc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[$P{_JRS_ADHOC_CHART_STATE}]]></jrhc:propertyExpression>
      </jrhc:chartProperty>
      <jrhc:chartProperty name="_JRS_ADHOC_QUERY_DATA">
       <jrhc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[$P{_JRS_ADHOC_QUERY_DATA}]]></jrhc:propertyExpression>
      </jrhc:chartProperty>
     </jrhc:chartSetting>
    </jrhc:chart>
   </componentElement>
  </band>
 </title>
 <summary>
  <band height="138" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField hyperlinkType="Reference" hyperlinkTarget="Blank">
    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="220" y="15" width="119" height="30" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#7FFF00" uuid="65c04b7a-29e2-45b2-ad37-ff22d0c14032">
     <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class" value="btn"/>
     <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.id" value="idBtn"/>
     <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font size="24"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["View"]]></textFieldExpression>
    <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["myButton"]]></anchorNameExpression>
    <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://google.ru"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
    <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Click to view"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: It's standart report